# C++ Operator Overloading [ ] for lvalue and rvalue

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword, lvalue, rvalue

I made a class Array which holds an integer array. From the main function, I'm trying to get an element of the array in Array using [ ] as we do for arrays declared in main. I overloaded the operator [ ] as in the following code; the first function returns an lvalue and the second an rvalue (Constructors and other member functions are not shown.)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Array {
public:
   int& operator[] (const int index)
   {
      return a[index];
   }
   int operator[] (const int index) const
   {
      return a[index];
   }

private:
   int* a;
}
```

However, when I try to call those two functions from main, only the first function is accessed even when the variable is not used as an lvalue. I can't see the point of creating a separate function for an rvalue if everything can be taken care of just by using the lvalue function.

The following code is the main function I used (Operator << is appropriately overloaded.):

```
#include "array.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   Array array;
   array[3] = 5;                // lvalue function called
   cout << array[3] << endl;    // lvalue function called
   array[4] = array[3]          // lvalue function called for both
}
```

Is there any way I can call the rvalue function? Is it also necessary to define functions for both lvalue and rvalue?

Comment: The operators probably should be declared as returning `int&` and `const int&` rather than `Array`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. My bad

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second function is a `const member function` and it will be called if you have a `const` instance:

```
const Array array;
cout << array[3] << endl;  // rvalue function called
```

It isn't conventional to call these "lvalue" and "rvalue" functions.  And you could define the const one to return a const reference if you want.

Comment: The const function would be called but the result could not be assigned in this example.